# 7 dancers on a circle

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> 7 dancers are going to participate in a contest. They are initially placed in their positions basis the initial letter of their surname. 
>   At the second part of the contest, they are given random positions around the circle, which are determined by a draw. What is the probability that none of the dancers are in their initial positions or their neighboring?

It seems very simple to me but obviously isn't. For each dancer, the probability is $\frac47$ so for all 7 it is $\frac{4^7}{7^7}$ – very simplistic, no?

Comment: Why $4/7$? I would have understood your intention if you had said $6/7$ (which still does not give the right answer, unless the random assignment allows several dancers in the same position)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I said 4/7 because if they are not allowed their initial position and the two neighboring, then, out of the 7 positions, they are only allowed in the 4, right?

Comment: Are the positions of the circle absolute or are they determined relative to the other dancers? Otherwise, everyone could move at least two spaces away from their position, but the configuration could still be the same afterwards.

Comment: Be careful. If the first dancer moves to position 3, the second dancer has 5 slots from which to pick. So there are more cases than what you're thinking or you may have to think about the problem differently.

Comment: You can't just multiply the probabilities, because the events are not independent.  Suppose that dancers $1,2,$ and $3$ are assigned to positions $4,5,$ and $6$ in the second round.  Then the probability that dancer $5$ is assigned to an admissible position is $1.$

Comment: Additionally, If @Paul is correct, then what you'll want to do is take the first 4 dancers and figure out how many ways there are to put dancers between dancers 1 and 2, 2 and 3, and 3 and 4.

Comment: @TomGalle Sorry, I simply did not notice the neighbouring restriction

Comment: The answer must be of the form $N/7!$ (since there are $7!$ ways the dances can rearrange themselves around the circle), so $4^7/7^7$ cannot be correct.

Comment: "For each dancer, the probability is"  the probability of any *one* dancer being it a different place is $\frac 47$ but the dancers possition effections the available options for the the rest.  The outcomes are not independent.  For example.  If dancer 1 is in dancer 2s position then dancer 2 does not have 4 out of 7 options but has only 4 out of 6 options.  And if dancer 1 is not in any of the places next to dancer 2 then dance 2 doesn't have 4 out of 7 options but has 3 out of 6 options as dancer 2 and dancer 1 can't both be in the same place.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is asking for the number of permutations of $\{0,\dots,6\}$ such that the difference between each element and its image is more than 1 (modulo 7), as a proportion of the total number of permutations. The permutations must have no fixed points, which means they can only have four types of cycle structures – $\{7\}, \{5,2\},\{4,3\},\{2,2,3\}$ – and these give rise to eleven patterns for permuting the dancers around:

[image]

Except for the two starry 7-cycles, each pattern can be in any of 7 orientations. They can also have $2^n$ cycle directions, where $n$ is the number of cycles that are not transpositions, written in the top-left corner of each permutation in the picture. Thus we have $7(8\cdot2+4)+2+2=144$ admissible permutations, and this is out of $7!=5040$, so the desired probability is $\frac{144}{5040}=\frac1{35}$.

---

Permutations of this sort, where elements move more than one place around a circle, are termed *discordant* and enumerated (with links to a general enumeration system) under [OEIS A000183](https://oeis.org/A000183).

Comment: @Parcly Taxel: Thank you very much for your solution. Could you possibly be a little more analytic? I don't quite understand the part with the patterns, modulo 7 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I get $144.$  I did this by computing the permanent of an appropriate matrix.  (See my answer here([Combinatorial Analysis - Specific problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959699/combinatorial-analysis-specific-problem/2959718#2959718)) for an explanation of this method.

The matrix in question is a $7\times7$ matrix with a $1$ in position $(i,j)$ is dancer $i$ is allowed to occupy position $j$ and zeros elsewhere.

I append the script, though I would not recommend using a python script to compute the permanent of a large matrix.

```
#perm01.py
'''
Compute the permanent of a 0-1 matrix
'''

import numpy as np
from math import factorial

def minor(M, i, j):
    return np.delete(np.delete(M,i,axis=0), j, axis=1)

def perm(M):
    size = M.shape[0]
    colsums = sum(M)
    rowsums = sum(M.transpose())
    c = np.argmin(colsums)
    r = np.argmin(rowsums)
    answer = 0
    if colsums[c] <= rowsums[r]:
        if colsums[c] == size:
            return factorial(size)
        for k in range(size):
            if M[k, c] == 1:
                answer += perm(minor(M,k,c))
    else:
        for k in range(size):
            if M[r, k] == 1:
                answer += perm(minor(M,r,k)) 
    return answer

if __name__=='__main__':
    M = np.zeros((7,7), dtype=np.int)
    for k in range(7):
        M[k,k]=M[k,(k+1)%7]=M[k,(k-1)%7]=1
    M = np.ones((7,7), dtype=int)-M
    print(perm(M))
```